# Multiple animation in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, animation

I have the following in *Mathematica*:

```
xx = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
yy = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};
xy = Transpose[{xx, yy}] // Partition[#, 3] &;
ani = ListPlot[#] & /@ xy;
Animate[ani]
```

The above code gives me a nice animation. But I want to draw an arrow and want it to move in a synchronous way with the animation. For drawing arrow I am using:

```
Animate[Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {xx[[i]], yy[[i]]}}]], {i, 1, Length[xx], 1}];
```

How can both the animations be displayed on same figure and in a synchronous manner? Thanks in advance. Here is a link to a `.gif` file which I generated in *MATLAB*. I am trying something like this on *Mathematica*:

[image]

Comment: @RunnyKine Here is the new question. I have also provided link to a .gif which I am hoping to generate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I post this for illustrative purposes (without attempting to exactly reproduce).[if can be be controlled by one parameter or function of parameter]:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[Exp[-(t + p)^2], {t, -3 - p, 3 - p}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-8, 3}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True],
   ParametricPlot[RotationMatrix[p].{t , t^2}, {t, -1, 1}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-4, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
    Epilog -> {{Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {-3, -1}}]}, 
      Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {-3, 0} + {Cos[p], -Sin[p]}}]}]
   }],
 {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

To export (gif or  mov etc) just change head to `Table` and choose suitable step size.

[image]

Comment: +1, I'd like to know that how to generate the dynamical graphic that you dragthe  parameter bar.

Comment: @Tangshutao this is just a screen capture of `Manipulate` object. I use: LiceCap: http://licecap.en.softonic.com/ You may have your own favourite.

Comment: ,Ok, I see.thanks sincerely! :-)

Comment: +1 For the interesting use of `RotationMatrix`.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you for your answer. I am sorry for my late reply. Your solution works perfectly for the case you have shown. But what happens if I have {x,y} points from array instead of having it from manipulate both for arrows and the curve. How can I use manipulate then?

Comment: Iam using this and it is not working: `Manipulate[
 Column[{ListPlot[#, Joined -> True] & /@ xy, 
   Arrow[{{-0.2, 0.4} , {-0.2, 0.4} + 0.4 {Sin[p], -Cos[p]}}]}], {p, 
  0, Pi/2}]` and it is not working

Comment: Is`Manipulate[
 Column[{ListPlot[#, Joined -> True] & /@ xy, 
   Graphics@
    Arrow[{{-0.2, 0.4}, {-0.2, 0.4} + 0.4 {Sin[p], -Cos[p]}}]}], {p, 
  0, Pi/2}]` what you wanted