# Multiple animations in Mathematica rows and columns

Tags: plotting, manipulate, column, row

I am trying to generalize the problem on this thread:

[Multiple animation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61169/multiple-animation-in-mathematica?newreg=0f66494000b440a3b776ee22db170d12)

by including additional plots on the right-hand side of the main plot (the gaussian one). For ease, I will be using the same working example as in the previous thread.

My first attempt was to include "Row" to the code:

```
Animate[Row[{Column[{Plot[Exp[-(t + p)^2], {t, -3 - p, 3 - p}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-8, 3}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True], 
     ParametricPlot[RotationMatrix[p].{t, t^2}, {t, -1, 1}, 
      Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-4, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
      Epilog -> {{Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {-3, -1}}]}, 
        Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {-3, 0} + {Cos[p], -Sin[p]}}]}]}], 
   ParametricPlot[RotationMatrix[p].{t, t^2}, {t, -1, 1}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-4, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
    Epilog -> {{Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {-3, -1}}]}, 
      Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {-3, 0} + {Cos[p], -Sin[p]}}]}]}], {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

However, I get the following animation:

[image]

Is there a way I can place these last plots right next to the main plot (at the same height)?

Comment: If you want all three of them to be in the same row, drop the ``Column`` and just use one row: ``Row[{Plot[...], ParametricPlot[...], ParametricPlot[...]}]``.

Comment: I want one of them to be below and the other one on the right-hand side.

Comment: Then use ``Grid[{{Plot[...], ParametricPlot[...]}, {ParametricPlot[...], ""}}]``.